# lazy_static global string will not print

Tags: rust, atom-editor

I have written this code and I keep having problems... The string will not print and I do not know what I'm doing wrong here...

```rust
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use std::io::{self, Write};
use std::sync::Mutex;

lazy_static! {
    static ref example: Mutex<String> = Mutex::new("example string".to_string());
}

fn main(){
    println!("{}", example);
}
```

I don't know where I went wrong I'm new to this whole rust thing but I know I need to use a global mutable variable here with lazy_static so I need this to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`example` is not a string. It is a `Mutex` containing a `String`. You have to `lock` the mutex before accessing its contents:

```
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use std::io::{self, Write};
use std::sync::Mutex;

lazy_static! {
    static ref example: Mutex<String> = Mutex::new("example string".to_string());
}

fn main(){
    println!("{}", example.lock().expect("Could not lock mutes"));
}
```

Source: Quoting https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html:

> Each mutex has a type parameter which represents the data that it is
>   protecting. The data can only be accessed through the RAII guards
>   returned from `lock` and `try_lock`, which guarantees that the data is
>   only ever accessed when the mutex is locked.

Comment: Thank you so much I had tried to lock it with no luck and I remember that I forgot the .expect() part